# Can't define options on bootstrap multiselect inputs when using 'dataprovider' method to generate list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using the [bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) extension to create drop down menus that allow multiple selection, have a search feature, and have a 'select all' option. This much is pretty easy:

```
$('#my-selector').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
});
```

Now I want to generate these dropdowns programmatically (from an AJAX response): to do so, the documentation recommends using the 'dataprovider' method. I can't figure out how to accomplish this while preserving the `enableFiltering` and `includeSelectAllOption` options.

My intuition is that I should be doing something like this:

```
$('#example-dataprovider').multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});  

var options = [
  {label: 'Option 1', title: 'Option 1', value: '1'},
  {label: 'Option 2', title: 'Option 2', value: '2'},
  {label: 'Option 3', title: 'Option 3', value: '3'},
  {label: 'Option 4', title: 'Option 4', value: '4'},
  {label: 'Option 5', title: 'Option 5', value: '5'},
  {label: 'Option 6', title: 'Option 6', value: '6'}
];

$('#example-dataprovider').multiselect('dataprovider', options);
```

But this doesn't work. I can get the `data-provider` method to work if I invokes a simpler `multiselect` call to construct the form:

```
$('#example-dataprovider').multiselect();
```

But then I can't figure out how to add filtering and selectAll after the fact.

How do I specify filtering and selectAll options on a dropdown that I construct programmatically?

Here's a [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/davidmarx/djm4ntL7/2/)

Comment: Your intuition was right. It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/8mL873o0/

Comment: Very strange... not sure why my code wasn't working after playing with your fiddle.

Comment: Got it working. Can't remember what it was that I changed, but it works now. Thanks for steering me back on track!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution,

```
var options = [
  {label: 'Option 1', title: 'Option 1', value: '1'},
  {label: 'Option 2', title: 'Option 2', value: '2'},
  {label: 'Option 3', title: 'Option 3', value: '3'},
  {label: 'Option 4', title: 'Option 4', value: '4'},
  {label: 'Option 5', title: 'Option 5', value: '5'},
  {label: 'Option 6', title: 'Option 6', value: '6'}
];

$('#example-dataprovider').multiselect('dataprovider', options);
var selectconfig = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
};
$('#example-dataprovider').multiselect('setOptions', selectconfig);
$('#example-dataprovider').multiselect('rebuild');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. I feel like this isn't how I'm "supposed" to be using this tool, but it seems to work. I'd still be interested to learn why the `dataprovider` method doesn't appear to be working the way I expected it to.

Anyway, my current solution is to use d3 to replace the `<option>` elements with whatever I want, and then call the multiselect 'rebuild' method to reconstruct the widget.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-filterBehavior').multiselect({
        enableFiltering: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        selectAllValue: 'select-all-value',
        selectAllName: 'select-all-name',
        filterBehavior: 'value',
        selectedClass: 'multiselect-selected'
    });
});


var options = [{'value':1, 'title':'First'},
               {'value':2, 'title':'Second'}];

form = d3.selectAll('#example-filterBehavior');

form.selectAll('option').remove();

form.selectAll('option')
    .data(options)
    .enter().append('option')
    .attr('value', function(d){return d.value})
    .text(function(d){return d.title});

 $('#example-filterBehavior').multiselect('rebuild');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidmarx/58m36eay/1/) for posterity.